# Intuition behind Factoring $(6)$ in $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

It turns out that we have (ideal equality) $$(6)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2(3,1+\sqrt{-5})(3,1-\sqrt{-5})$$ How does one get this from $(6)=(2)(3)$?

When factoring $(6)$ how do we know to continue to factor $(2), (3)$? Why do we have $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$?

$2$ belongs to the left hand side, but it's not in the right hand side due to the square.

Comment: 2 belongs to the right hand side as $2 = 6-4 = (1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}) - 2^2$

Comment: $2$ is in right hand side: since $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ is simply the ideal generated by $2^2, 2.(1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $(1+\sqrt{-5})^2=-4+4\sqrt{-5}$. From these three generators, we can easily obtain $2$; can you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $(2)=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$ is one of ideals.

To see it, let us consider $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})^2$.

It is $$(2,1+\sqrt{-5})(2,1+\sqrt{-5}) = (4, 2( 1+  \sqrt{-5}), (1+\sqrt{-5})^2) = (4, 2 +  2\sqrt{-5}), -4+2\sqrt{-5}).$$ 
Since $2 = (2 +  2\sqrt{-5})) - (-4+2\sqrt{-5}))$ the right-hand side in fact contains.